# Giving default page to a project

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a project in php and iis. All the files are in a folder public. Every time I have to type this entire url to enter a page. Is it possible to type just space and enter any default page of the project?

```
 localhost/space/SPACE_V01.01.13/Source/Source_code/public/xxxx.php
```

If `localhost/space/SPACE_V01.01.13/Source/Source_code/public`  is given, I can set a default page using iis manager default document option. But I need to go to that document only if `localhost/space` is given.

Comment: set document root path in httpd.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a index.php file in your root directory of localhost and place just the following code in it.

```
<?php
header("Location:localhost/space/SPACE_V01.01.13/Source/Source_code/public/xxxx.php");
?>
```

And make sure there is no other index file in your root directory wheather .html or .php

Hope it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you type the url of your site in a browser like this:

http://www.example.com

the browser will look at the root directory of your website for a file named "index.php" or "default.php" to load. The same happens when you open a folder inside your root directory:

http://www.example.com/Blog/

If you don't have a site named "index.php" or "default.php" it will just show you a list of the elements the directory contains and it should look like this:

[image]

So, all you need to do is create a file named "index.php" or "default.php" and it will be loaded as default, when you are trying to access a folder on your site. From there, you can redirect to another page in your project using PHP or JavaScript:

default.php

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/anothersite.php');
?>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/anothersite.php");
</script>
```